# when try to make database separated comma i get error invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I work on SQL Server 2012 I face error and I don't know how to solve error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
> Column '#servers.ServerId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What I need to do is display database separated comma for every application and server, because every application have one server and every server have multi database.

What I tried is :

```
SELECT
    p.ApplicationId,
    S.ServerName,
    [DataBase]= STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + pt.DatabaseName
                       FROM #Database pt
                       WHERE S.ServerId = pt.ServerId
                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
FROM 
    #application p
INNER JOIN 
    #servers S ON S.ServerId = P.ServerId
GROUP BY
    p.ApplicationId, S.ServerName
ORDER BY 
    p.ApplicationId, S.ServerName
```

Code table details

```
CREATE TABLE #application
(
    ApplicationId int,
    ServerId int
)

INSERT INTO #application (ApplicationId, ServerId)
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2)

CREATE TABLE #servers
(
    ServerId int,
    ServerName nvarchar(50),
)

INSERT INTO #servers (ServerId, ServerName)
VALUES (1, 'LinuxServer'),
       (2, 'WindowsServer')

CREATE TABLE #Database
(
    DatabaseId int,
    ServerId int,
    DatabaseName nvarchar(50),
)

INSERT INTO #Database (DatabaseId, ServerId, DatabaseName)
VALUES (1, 1, 'DB1'), (2, 1, 'DB2'),
       (3, 2, 'DB3'), (4, 2, 'DB4')
```

Expected result

[image: stuff for multi database]

Comment: Aside, it's well past time you considered upgrading, then you can utilise the latest features such as string aggregation.

Comment: can you please help me provide solution please by stuff

Comment: If you add the colum  it tells you is a problem to your `GROUP BY` (as the error suggests) what happens..?

Comment: can you tell me more details i don't understand can you please write answer by code please

Comment: Include `,S.ServerId `  into `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: use ANY_VALUE(fieldname) in the select for the fieldnames not used in the group by statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `group by` because `for xml path('')` would generate an aggregated string for each application and server.

Here is the code that will generate your expected result:

```
select
    ApplicationId,
    ServerName,
    stuff (Databases, 1, 2, N'')
from
(
    select
        a.ApplicationId,
        s.ServerName,
        (
            select ', ' + d.DatabaseName
            from #Database d
            where d.ServerId = s.ServerId
            order by d.DatabaseName
            for xml path('')
        ) Databases
    from #application a
    inner join #servers s on s.ServerId = a.ServerId
) q
order by ApplicationId, ServerName
```

*suggestion1:* Use `stuff` after implementing `for xml path('')`.

*suggestion2:* Make sure to use `order by` in your `for xml path('')` query, so databases listed alphabetically.

**note:** There is not possible two identical database name in same server, so `distinct` is not necessary.